# Swift equivalent of a simple JavaScript object declaration

Tags: swift

Considering the following JavaScript object:

```
const car = {type:"Fiat", model:"500", color:"white"};
```

What would be the equivalent structure in `Swift` language, written in such a short line of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also do:

```swift
let car = (type: "Fiat", model: "500", color: "white")
```

But in my opinion, it is much cleaner to define your objects by using structs.

Comment: Ah, forgot about tuples :) Also a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

Swift is a strongly typed language. If you want to initialize an object, you have to define its type first. Javascript is weakly typed and apart of that it doesn't even distinguish between objects and dictionaries (or arrays).

In Swift, you could write

```
let car = ["type": "Fiat", "model": "500", "color": "white"]
```

to create a `[String: String]` dictionary, but that would be a bad idea in this case. Instead, you should properly declare a type:

```
struct Car {
   let type: String
   let model: String
   let color: String
}
```

and then initialize it:

```
let car = Car(type: "Fiat", model: "500", color: "white")
```

which is almost the same as in Javascript, only with types.

Types give you more power and "shorter" does not mean "better".

Comment: Yes sure. A Swift class would be an even closer equivalent (reference type), right? Which would mean the need of an init() on top of that... So if I understand, there isn't such a "shortcut" as in JavaScript. Of course *"shorter" does not mean "better"*, completely agree. I was just wondering if there was a shorter syntax.

Comment: @Kassagi The type definition has to be somewhere. In Swift the code to define a type is actually much simpler than in Typescript, or flow.

Comment: The type can be anonymous. Use a tuple like in the other answer, but without a type alias.

Comment: @Jessy With an anonymous type it's very difficult to pass the type to a function. Or store it somewhere.

Comment: For sure, but it matches the question.